# Meaning of $dx^3$ in an integral?

Tags: calculus

In the integral $\iiint y^3x^2\,dx^3$ what does the $dx^3$ mean? I interpret it as being shorthand for $dx\,dx\,dx$ because you need three differentials for a triple integral and since the $dx$ is a single variable. But I'm not very familiar with triple integrals and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @user326159 I'd say that the OP's interpretation is correct, usually $dx^3 = dx\,dx\,dx$.

Comment: @user326159 if we were to be using $dxdydz$ why would that be shortened to $dx^3$?

Comment: $dx^3$ can also mean $3x^2dx$ in the case of an integral, but it doesn't seem to be right in the context of a triple integral.

Comment: It might help to see more of the context in which this came up. Will the integrals be made definite? Or is it possible that we're looking at the third antiderivative of a constant $y^3$ times $x^2$?

Comment: Yep, that would be noted $dV$ for $dxdydz$ as a volume infinitesimal, or maybe it was meant for $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$ with a bold face $x$ on LHS, may happens in books composition. Nonetheless David K's proposal that it might be a triple anti-derivative rather than a triple integral is also to be considered.

Comment: @BernardMassé i might be a bit slow, how do we get from $dx^3$ to $3x^2dx$ in the context of an integral?

Comment: @moxy by the usual calculus of differentials.

Comment: @DavidK There isn't any particular context that i know of, I guess it is just an example of a triple integral. There might be more but I found it left on a whiteboard. The $dx^3$ got me curious so i copied it over to ask on here later.

Comment: @BernardMassé ah so it's a differential? like $y = x^3$ so $dy/dx = 3x^2 \implies dy = 3x^2 dx$. Something like that? How would that even look like in an integral?

Comment: "On a whiteboard" is some context; it raises the chance that this is an informal shorthand (to save time), in contrast to finding it in a book. If there was any further calculation that you remember, that might help too.